# Output redirection in batch while using start command

Tags: java, batch-file, command-line, jar

### I have to run a jar several time in one shot and redirect the output to a different files. so i am using a batch which is as follows :

start java -jar app.jar > log1.out ;

start java -jar app.jar > log2.out ;

start java -jar app.jar > log3.out ;

### pause

it launches the three parallel instance. But output does not get redirected to file, it shows output on console only .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this for redirection

```
start cmd /c java -jar app.jar ^> log1.out
```

Don't forget the `^`. It's used as an escape here. In the absence of the `^`, the `>` will be taken as a redirect to the `start` rather than to `java`.

Answer (score 2):

```
start cmd /c java -jar app.jar ^> log1.out  ^2^>^&1
```

will redirect stderr to wherever you are sending stdout

```
start cmd /k java -jar app.jar ^> log1.out  ^2^>^&1
```

/k will keep the window open, allowing you to debug your attempts to get this to work

Comment: It looks like `^` in front of `2` is optional, it works even without it.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the commands in the background with /b, as follows:

```
start /b java -jar app.jar > log1.out ;
start /b java -jar app.jar > log2.out ;
start /b java -jar app.jar > log3.out ;
```

(The /wait flag can also interesting to avoid parallel processing.)