# Batch file: How to redirect output from .exe with parameter?

Tags: windows, batch-file, exe

I am trying to write a batch file to run a .exe with a parameter and that gives and output in .csv

I wrote:

```
start "" "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\AnalysisSoftware\Video.exe" S1.avi>S1.csv
```

This command is working but the created .csv file is empty. What's wrong?
I also tried with ^ like that:

```
start "" "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\AnalysisSoftware\Video.exe" S1.avi^>S1.csv
```

Not working too...

Thank you

Cec

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output redirection in batch while using start command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681090/output-redirection-in-batch-while-using-start-command)

Answer (score 1):

The start command starts the command in another process and so the output is not captured, instead you are capturing the output of the start command, which is nothing.

What you need is

```
start "" "cmd /c C:\Users\Me\Desktop\AnalysisSoftware\Video.exe S1.avi>S1.csv"
```

The distinction here is that the redirection operator is within the quotes.  In your example above the redirection operator was outside the quotes and so it captured the output of the start command instead of the Video.exe.  Note you also need to use cmd /c at the beginning.  This is because you need a shell in order to redirect the output of the Video.exe.  The /c argument tells cmd to exit as soon as the command finishes executing.

Comment: Nope - START will treat the entire quoted string as the name of the executable, and it will  fail because of the presence of the argument and the redirection.

Comment: Oops - sorry. I missed the CMD /C in your answer - that indeed should work, assuming Video.exe writes properly to stdout.